Magnetic field due to a conducting spherical shell connected to two wires
A conducting spherical shell of radius $R$ is connected to two perpendicular long wires, as shown in the figure. A current $I$ flows through the system, and the current flows in such a way that no charge is piled anywhere on the shell. Find the magnitude of the magnetic field
at point P, located just outside the surface of the shell, right in the middle between the vertical wire and the horizontal wire.

I have no idea how the current flows here so I tried instead to consider a different system:

This one could be solved more easily by symmetry and Ampère's Law, as the current should flow evenly in all directions with the total current still being $I$ throughout. So the magnetic field along a loop of radius $r$ (coaxial with the wires) is purely azimuthal and of equal magnitude
$B_\phi = {\mu_0I\over{2{\pi}r}}$
(outside the spherical shell. Inside the shell the magnetic field is zero since the enclosed current would be zero.)
So with that in mind we could consider this system:

which is just a superposition between two copies of the previous system (one copy being rotated 90°). So the resultant magnetic field at point P would be $2 \times {\mu_0I\over{2{\pi}R \sin(45°)}}$ and to get the original system (with twice the current) I would just have to take the superposition with this system:

Trouble is, I have no idea on how I could find the magnetic field for this last system. All I know is that at all the
four corners
$(R, \pi/4, 0), (R, 3\pi/4, 0), (R, 5\pi/4, 0), (R, 7\pi/4, 0)$
the magnitude of the magnetic fields are the same.

There should be no current flowing in the steady state, otherwise we wouldn't be dealing with a perfect conductor here. So the field should be purely due to the two wires.

Then how would current be getting from one wire to the other? OP states that "no charge is piled anywhere on the shell."

Even if it's a perfect conductor, surely the charges don't just instantly appear on the other side...I should think?
